# How to translate APT-Get install packages to YUM

Tags: centos, apt, yum

I have a Raspberry PI, which I am required to use CentOS 7.   I am also trying to use the papirus eInk display  (https://github.com/PiSupply/PaPiRus)

The drivers and dependencies installation instructions use Apt-Get,  but CentOS uses YUM.  What the best/easiest method to install these dependencies is?

I've seen instructions on how to install Apt-Get on CentOS but the consensus there is that its a bad idea. YUM is much better on CentOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complex issue because the two are not compatible for multiple reasons and so direct conversion from one to the other is generally very tricky.

## A little background

`apt` (`apt-get`) is a package manager for installing Debian style `.dpkg` packages and their dependencies.

`yum` is a package manager for installing red-hat `.rpm` style packages and their dependencies.

Before you even begin to discuss the direct compatibility issues between .`dpkg` and `.rpm` files there is a more general issue that `.dpkg`/`apt-get` dependencies will have been figured out for [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/).  *These will not match the dependencies for CentOS.*  Not only do the two operating systems use different package names they also have different versions of respective packages installed.  This means that even on another Debian-like operating system such as Ubuntu you might still have problems.

In short the `.dpkg`/`apt-get` packages will not be useful to you on CentOS.

## Added complication

As the package you're trying to install is python related, there is a third package manager to be aware of: [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/).  This *can* be installed alongside yum but remember that when you install with yum, you also allow yum to upgrade those packages as newer ones become available.  With pip you would need to ask pip to upgrade periodically because yum won't do that for you.

## What can you do?

You can try searching on the command line: eg `yum search pil`.  But honestly I prefer Google for this task.  It gives you much more context for synonyms of package names.  You don't really have much of a choice but to work through the named dependencies yourself and find similar packages for CentOS and / or pip.  This will involve a lot of time on Google to work out the correct list.

For example (assuming you are installing with `yum` and not `pip`), the instruction to:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pil python-smbus python-dateutil -y
```

Here I would google for three things:

1. centos package python pil
2. centos package python smbus
3. centos package python dateutil

Eventually leading me to install packages with yum:

```
yum install python-pillow i2c-tools-python python-dateutil
```

Notice that `python-pil` became `python-pillow`.  This is a fork of the same package but will hopefully be compatible.  Notice also that `python-smbus` became `i2c-tools-python`.  [This appears to be the correct package name on Centos](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/i2c-tools-python-3.1.0-13.el7.x86_64.rpm.html)

If you really can't find the right python package as an RPM then you might be forced to [install it with pip](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/).

## If that doesn't work

As I mentioned earlier, package versions might not match meaning that dependencies fail.  When you've installed everything you can and it still doesn't work.  Your next step should be to go back to the software maintainers (on GitHub) and ask them *politely if they would mid* to help you figure out the CentOS dependencies.

Comment: Thank you this was enough of pointer to get me to point.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the part that is causing you trouble is this:

```
# Install dependencies
sudo apt-get install git bc i2c-tools fonts-freefont-ttf whiptail make gcc -y
# For Python 2
sudo apt-get install python-pil python-smbus python-dateutil -y
# For Python 3
sudo apt-get install python3-pil python3-smbus python3-dateutil -y
```

First I would suggest making sure epel-release is installed (an additional repository for yum):

```
yum -y install epel-release
```

now you can search an equivalent for each of these packages and install it: for example:

```
yum search i2c
```

gave me:

```
i2c-tools.x86_64 : A heterogeneous set of I2C tools for Linux
i2c-tools-eepromer.x86_64 : Programs for reading / writing i2c / smbus eeproms
i2c-tools-python.x86_64 : Python bindings for Linux SMBus access through i2c-dev
```

so luckily the package has the same name; I can thus run:

```
yum install i2c-tools
```

If you are lucky; all package names will be the same; but it is possible that some differ. just try it out :)